# iOS: How I can check if FirstApp open the appstore if the SecondApp was not installed else open SecondApp directly?

Tags: ios, url

I have an applications, will namely FirstApp and SecondApp, that i would like the FirstApp will open app store if SecondApp was not installed else it will open SecondApp directly.

How will i add a checking if the SecondApp was installed or not so that i can call a specific url scheme to open app store or the app directly?

Answer (score 4):

If your "SecondApp" already exposes a URL-schema you can just find out if the app is installed by calling UIApplication's `- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`

Comment: you are just right in time brother. i found the answer my self. haha

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

I just added a url scheme under `URL Schemes` in the Info.plist, which was firstapp for my FirstApp and secondApp for my SecondApp then on my button `Open Other App` button i added these lines of code:

```
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"secondApp://"]]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"secondApp://"]];
        } else {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appname/appid?ls=1&mt=8"]];
        }
```

same way for `Open Other App` button in SecondApp just changed it to `@"firstapp://"`

It works like charm! :)